# Visual studio 2015 project missing all references

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Starting from today, a WPF project that belongs to a solution with 20 projects, set all my references to missing

[image]

I've just checked the MS suggestion and the other answers on Stackoverflow but none worked...I've tried to re-get solution from SVN, with no luck, other colleagues haven't got this problem.
I've also tried to remove and re-add the references (System.Xml for example) .
But no way to make it work...

Any suggestion?
Thanks

## UPDATE #1

Here's the csproj

```
 <ItemGroup>
<Reference Include="Catel.Core, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Catel.Core.4.2.0\lib\net40\Catel.Core.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Catel.Extensions.Controls, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Catel.Extensions.Controls.4.2.0\lib\net40\Catel.Extensions.Controls.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Catel.Extensions.FluentValidation, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Catel.Extensions.FluentValidation.4.2.0\lib\net40\Catel.Extensions.FluentValidation.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Catel.Fody.Attributes, Version=2.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1c8163524cbe02e6, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Catel.Fody.2.8.0\lib\portable-net4+sl4+wp7+win8+wpa81+MonoAndroid14+MonoTouch40\Catel.Fody.Attributes.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Catel.MVVM, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Catel.MVVM.4.2.0\lib\net40\Catel.MVVM.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="MethodTimer, Version=1.15.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cb1364609f40a1dc, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\MethodTimer.Fody.1.15.7.0\Lib\portable-net4+sl5+wp8+win8+wpa81+MonoAndroid16+MonoTouch40\MethodTimer.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>False</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Threading.Tasks, Version=1.0.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Async.1.0.168\lib\net40\Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=1.0.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Async.1.0.168\lib\net40\Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.Desktop, Version=1.0.168.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Async.1.0.168\lib\net40\Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.Desktop.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="PresentationCore" />
<Reference Include="PresentationFramework" />
<Reference Include="ServiceStack">
  <HintPath>..\packages\ServiceStack.4.0.46\lib\net40\ServiceStack.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="ServiceStack.Client, Version=4.0.46.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\ServiceStack.Client.4.0.46\lib\net40\ServiceStack.Client.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="ServiceStack.Common">
  <HintPath>..\packages\ServiceStack.Common.4.0.46\lib\net40\ServiceStack.Common.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="ServiceStack.Interfaces, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e06fbc6124f57c43, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\ServiceStack.Interfaces.4.0.46\lib\portable-wp80+sl5+net40+win8+monotouch+monoandroid+xamarin.ios10\ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="ServiceStack.Text, Version=4.0.46.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\ServiceStack.Text.4.0.46\lib\net40\ServiceStack.Text.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System" />
<Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
<Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
<Reference Include="System.Core" />
<Reference Include="System.IO, Version=2.6.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.1.1.10\lib\net40\System.IO.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Management" />
<Reference Include="System.Net" />
<Reference Include="System.Runtime, Version=2.6.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.1.1.10\lib\net40\System.Runtime.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Threading.Tasks, Version=2.6.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.1.1.10\lib\net40\System.Threading.Tasks.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Windows.Interactivity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Catel.MVVM.4.2.0\lib\net40\System.Windows.Interactivity.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Xaml" />
<Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
<Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
<Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
<Reference Include="System.Data" />
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
<Reference Include="System.Xml" />
<Reference Include="Telerik.Windows.Controls, Version=2015.2.728.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5803cfa389c90ce7, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Telerik.Windows.Controls.for.Wpf.40.Xaml.2015.2.728\lib\net40\Telerik.Windows.Controls.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView, Version=2015.2.728.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5803cfa389c90ce7, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.for.Wpf.40.Xaml.2015.2.728\lib\net40\Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Telerik.Windows.Controls.Input, Version=2015.2.728.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5803cfa389c90ce7, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Telerik.Windows.Controls.Input.for.Wpf.40.Xaml.2015.2.728\lib\net40\Telerik.Windows.Controls.Input.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation, Version=2015.2.728.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5803cfa389c90ce7, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation.for.Wpf.40.Xaml.2015.2.728\lib\net40\Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Telerik.Windows.Data, Version=2015.2.728.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5803cfa389c90ce7, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Telerik.Windows.Data.for.Wpf.40.Xaml.2015.2.728\lib\net40\Telerik.Windows.Data.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="UIAutomationProvider" />
<Reference Include="UIAutomationTypes" />
<Reference Include="WindowsBase" />
```

Yes I use Nuget, the other 19 points to the same assemblies ...nothing has been moved

## UPDATE #2

Since I was not able to proceed I've copied the project from a colleague and now it works.... think something went wrong in the filesystem...have compared the solution and they were identical

Comment: Could you paste the relevant parts of the .csproj file?

Comment: are the bin and obj folders empty or missing? Have you tried a rebuild? Do you use Nuget?

Comment: prob you dont get access to a folder with your libraries, either because they are not there or you dont have privileges, potentially somebody changes the paths to it, and they dont work for you anymore, check where csproj looks for them and if you can find them by yourself there

Comment: The fact that it's missing reference to things like `System` seems to indicate that this is more than a simple missing folder.

Comment: The other projects works fine...

Answer (score 204, accepted):

The resolution to this issue is.

Whenever you import a project to VS 2015 it modifies your .csproj. So, in order to fix it. Right click on .csproj and open it in notepad or any editor and delete the following

```
<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Error Condition="!Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets'))" />
</Target>
```

Then build your solution and it should work.

Comment: For anybody who doesn't know how to find `.csproj` file for edit, You can right click on your project and choose `Unload Project`, after this you will be able to edit the `.csproj` file

Comment: You can also navigate to the directory where you saved your project and right click .csproj and edited.

Comment: Yes! After much troubleshooting, this is finally what allowed me to add references without getting a yellow triangle - thank you!

Comment: Does anyone know why microsoft even does such a thing? This has caused me so much headaches! thanks.

Comment: I just spent nearly a week trying to track down Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props in my solution because that was the error that kept returning when attempting to build. So crazy this was the solution. Wow. Thank you.

Comment: If you need to not unload your project before you find the csproj file, you should go to folder directory of you project and open the csproj from there on notepad or other similar viewer, i found the best ones to be notepad++

Answer (score 10):

In the root directory of the solution, delete everything inside of `/packages/` folder, then do a re-build.

Comment: For me it worked perfectly. All packages was downloaded from TFS and broken on my local. After applying this solution it was rebuilded without any issue. Thanks @mmcrae.

Comment: I just deleted my entire packages folder but it also worked

Answer (score 10):

It can help to force rebuild the nuget packages. Go to the nuget console and use the following commands: (TOOLS > Options > Package Manager > Package Manager Conbsole)

```
Update-Package -reinstall -ProjectName "MyProject" -safe
```

The safe parameter will actually not update the packages, but only reinstall them. If that didn't help, you can try to actually update them (but make sure you have a copy of the project somewhere, just in case.)

```
Update-Package -reinstall -ProjectName "MyProject"
```

To force update just one package, use:

```
Update-Package -id Microsoft.Package.Name -ProjectName "MyProject"
```

Comment: This solution has worked for me many times as well, proving there is always more than one way to accomplish your goal

Answer (score 3):

I had this once, caused by a broken .targets import. Check if you accidentally enabled nuget package restore (which includes a .targets file) and then deleted the .nuget directory.

Comment: i had a similar problem... strangely after updating my nuget packages  all the references were restored

Comment: @jan-seins - what exactly do you mean "updating my nuget packages"? What did you do in VS?

Comment: @mmcrae - i just went on tools > nuget package manager > nuget packages for solutions. Under updates I hade a pending update for System.Data.SQLite. After I updated it all references were restored. I don't say that this is a solution. it's just how it worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue. The solution, which worked for me was to pop the nuget package manager for the solution and refresh the packages.

Another case involved missing packages and nuget package manager for the solution showed updates and dependencies, which needed to be installed and this was the fix.

Another case was exactly as pointed above - delete packages folder fixed it.

Editing manually the project is an option, but there is a chance if you poke where you are not supposed to, your project may not open. If you can, avoid doing that is my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I've just experienced exactly this in VS2015 on a solution with around 20 projects. Only one project was affected and it lost all references including to the standard .NET assemblies.

The only way I could resolve was to switch to a different GIT branch and then back, this cleaned up the issue and it is all now working.

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced exactly this in VS2015 on a solution with around 10 projects. Only one project - the main MVC project - was affected and it lost all references including to the standard .NET assemblies.

The problem was in my web.config. I had commented some lines, resulting in an invalid xml-file.

Answer (score 1):

This error may occur if you miss `.targets` file in nuget `packages` folder. In my case it was
`packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets`

Usually it happens when I'm adding packages to git repository (common `.gitignore` file is ignoring build folder everywhere) and checkout on another computer.

Tip: you can modify `.gitignore` file to include all files in `packages` folder. Append these lines to the bottom:

```
# Include all files in NuGet packages directory
!/packages/**/
```

Answer (score 0):

For me I had mistakenly removed the following line from .csproj file:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
```

So I closed Visual Studio. Opened `myprojectname.csproj` file and added the line.
then I reopened the solution and by that I was able to resolve my issue.

Answer (score -2):

Unload project, then edit project

look for the following and delete.

This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.